# How do I make sbt output stack traces of TestFailedExceptions?

Tags: scala, exception, testing, sbt, scalatest

How do I make [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) output the stack traces of [TestFailedExceptions](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.7/org/scalatest/TestFailedException.html), as thrown by ScalaTest, instead of suppressing them, which seems to be the default?

We use the ['F' option to ScalaTest/sbt](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt), but it doesn't affect TestFailedException apparently.

Comment: Is it an interactive sbt session, could you use 'last' ?

Comment: @johanandren It is not interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScalaTest's F option](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt) actually does the trick. A bug in our build.sbt file cleared this option unfortunately, so it only looked as if it was enabled.